# How long has been the device on?

Tags: android

I would like to know how long the device has been on. Is there any way to know this information?
Like to get the boot up time or the seconds it is been on, or last shutdown time...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29

```
public static long uptimeMillis ()
```

Comment: long l = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();